# Is there a way to use file_put_contents() and store the cached contents in a different directory?

Tags: php, caching

I am able to put the file contents if I stay in the same directory level

ie:   `file_put_contents('cache.txt', $result);

But how would I put the contents up a folder, or even two?  Adding '../cache/cache.txt' does not seem to work.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would work fine assuming the user the web server runs as has write permission to that directory.

Comment: I ended up working this out. I had a foreach loop spit the cache files out.  They were a directory higher than where the resulting php script file was.  That was where the issue was regarding my inability to get the file_put_contents() to work correctly. Got it now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try using the direct path of where you would like to put the cache content.

```
<?php
$file = 'people.txt';
$cacheFile = __FILE__  . '/cache/'. $file;

$content = 'Something';

file_put_contents($file, $content);
file_put_contents($cacheFile, $content);

?>
```

Assuming you have a folder called cache, with write permissions to it.